# I want to fetch particular matched records from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

please help me with mysql query.

```
id       name       manual_id
------------------------------
1        windows    1,2
2        apple      1
3        linux      11,2
```

Consider above table. I want to fetch only records who contains `1`
so as per above table it should only fetch id 1 and 2 that contains "1". it should not get 11 as a result.
I tried using LIKE but it fetches manual_id 11 as well.
Give me exact way to fetch this record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `IN()` or `FIND_IN_SET()` functions.

Comment: It does not helped me much. it found partially only. By the thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE   
    manual_id LIKE '%,1,%' OR
    manual_id LIKE '1,%'
  OR  manual_id LIKE '%,1' OR
IF(manual_id = '1' AND CHAR_LENGTH(manual_id) = 1, true,'Invalid record')
```

Explanation : Here it will search for record with manual id LIKE '%,1,%' means Comma after AND before 1 . It will also check for '1,%,' it would be 1st number in that field . It will check for '%,1' too means last 1 . 
The last if condition is IF -> there is `1` only in record.

[**Working SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/349bc/4/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me and got exact result.

Comment: I tried it before two days but my reputation was not 15 so I could not upvote. Now I have exact 15 points so I can upvote now ;)

Comment: Nice.You can Accept the answer too by clicking on Tick mark button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`

```
SELECT * from `table`
WHERE `manual_id` IN (1);
```

Comment: First response using `IN()` after 12 mins. *Hey Sam!*

Comment: I was doing pretty things to spatial data. *Hey Ralph!*

Comment: Complete with dingo balls around the windows and dash too?

Comment: Yessir, all the dingo balls and fuzzy dice.

Comment: I can't wait to get my '64 lime green Impala!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from `table`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',`manual_id`)
```